# Angular 4 http get with multiple params to Spring Request Mapping

Tags: spring, angular, http

I'm trying to send a httpClient.get request with params and consume it in my Spring Controller. I want to send search criteria and return a list of objects according to that criteria.

This is my search.service.ts

```
 public getDentists(name, city, type, rating): Observable<Dentist[]>{

    let params = new HttpParams();
    params.set('name', name);
    params.set('city', city);
    params.set('type', type);
    params.set('rating', rating);

    return this.httpClient.get('dentists/', {params: params});
  }
```

in my controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dentists", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Dentist> search(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                         @RequestParam("city") String city,
                         @RequestParam("type") String type,
                         @RequestParam("rating") String rating) {

        return dentistRepository.findDentistByName(name);
}
```

This is what I get as an error:

[image]

- I also get this error: 
  2017-12-03 01:07:10.138  WARN 10108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present

My question is what am I doing wrong, why am I not receiving the params with requestparam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#description) is immutable. All the mutation operators return a new instance, so you have to do

```
let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', name)
    .set('city', city)
    .set('type', type)
    .set('rating', rating);
```

or

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('name', name);
params = params.set('city', city);
params = params.set('type', type);
params = params.set('rating', rating);
```

Comment: @JJey np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', name)
    .set('city', city)
    .set('type', type)
    .set('rating', rating);
```

HttpParams is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`append()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#append) method (instead of `add()`):

```
public getDentists(name, city, type, rating): Observable<Dentist[]>{

  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('name', name);
  params = params.append('city', city);
  params = params.append('type', type);
  params = params.append('rating', rating);

  return this.httpClient.get('dentists/', {params: params});
}
```

**UPDATE**

actually `append()` and `set()` methods will produce exactly the same result:

```
?name=NAME_VALUE&city-CITY_VALUE&type=TYPE_VALUE&rating=RATING_VALUE,
```

`append()` should be used when we want to append another value to existing key, something like:

```
?name=NAME1&name=NAME2_VALUE&.....
```

We also can use [`HttpParamsOptions`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L77) object passed to `HttpParams` constructor:

```
const params = new HttpParams({
  fromObject: {
    name,
    city,
    type,
    rating
  }
});
return this.httpClient.get('dentists/', {params});
```